# Updates installed on auto

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have found that my Samsung Galaxy SIII's Play Store is auto-updating applications without telling me anything. This is not acceptable, since it is updating apps most of which I never use. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Click on your Play Store icon
2. When the play store app opens click the 3 horizontal bars symbol (top left hand corner beside 'My Apps'
3. Click on Settings
4. Click on 'Auto-Update apps'
5. Then select 'Do not auto update apps'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, if the definition of the setting isn't lying, that should do the trick :). Thx.